# Cauchy Integral Theorem, Send Circle Radius to 0.

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I can’t seem to wrap my head around this old qual problem, despite it seeming rather straightforward. We are given a function $f$ that is continuous in a neighborhood around a point a. We are asked to show:

\begin{align*}
     f(a) = \left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\right) \; \text{lim}_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \int_{C_{\epsilon}(a)} \frac{f(z)}{z-a}dz
\end{align*}

Basically, show the Cauchy Integral Theorem holds. Now I know it holds when $f$ is analytic inside the disk and continuous up to the boundary, and in this case we are essentially removing the interior by shrinking the radius to 0, so it’s like the analytic requirement is mute and we just need the “continuous up to the boundary” portion, at least that is my intuition.

If someone could (a) tell me if my intuition is correct, and (b) help me start how I might argue this formally, that would be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: Is one of your questions essentially how to prove Cauchy's integral theorem?

Comment: For starters, this is the integral over the *circle* of radius $\epsilon$, not the disk. Yes, it’s just continuity. The hint is to subtract $f(a)$ from both sides.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah, of course. I’ve corrected that mistake. Could you please elaborate slightly on subtracting $f(a)$? I’ve thought about your comment, and it seems like, since $f$ is continuous, $f(z) \rightarrow f(a)$ as the disk shrinks. So the $f(z)$ in the numerator becomes $f(a)$, and the remaining integral integrates to $2\pi i$. I could try subtracting $f(a)$ and try to make something that looks like a difference quotient, but I don’t think that’s the right idea in this case. Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Your immediate intuition is correct. Just use the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ definition of limit.

Comment: Gotcha, I think I see how to proceed. I’ll finish the formal argument soon and post an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, parametrize $C_{\epsilon}(a)$ by $z = a + \epsilon e^{2\pi i\theta}$ to write

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_{\epsilon}(a)} \frac{f(z)}{z - a} \, \mathrm{d}z
= \int_{0}^{1} f(a + \epsilon e^{2\pi i \theta}) \, \mathrm{d}\theta. $$

So it follows that

$$ \left| \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_{\epsilon}(a)} \frac{f(z)}{z - a} \, \mathrm{d}z - f(a) \right|
\leq \int_{0}^{1} \left| f(a + \epsilon e^{2\pi i \theta}) - f(a) \right| \, \mathrm{d}\theta. $$

I guess now you know how to proceed.

Comment: Oh wow this is fantastic! Parameterizing so the bounds are 0 to 1 also makes it super clear, as I was caught up on getting the $-f(a)$ into the RHS integrand. Thank you so much!